# MySql VIEW ERROR 'View 'tablet_001.hisrec' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them'

Tags: mysql

When this is executed

```
SELECT count(*) FROM hisrec
```

this error appears

> View 'tablet_001.hisrec' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or
>   function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

if this is executed

```
SELECT COD FROM hisrec
```

the same error appears

but if this is executed

`SELECT * FROM hisrec`

all works fine :S

Why??

**im root.... with all privileges!**

Comment: How is `hisrec` defined?

Comment: is a normal view, in any computers the same view (other servers) work fine, but in some clients fail... (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tablet_001' AND TABLE_NAME = 'hisrec';
```

Check out your view and see what is the problem,if you don't know post it here.

Comment: I'm just curious, is there anything special in this command that `SHOW CREATE VIEW hisrec \G` couldn't retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on mysql 5.6.x.

`select * from view` worked.

`select count(*) from view` resulted in OP's error message.

Resolved by taking Order By clause out of the select ... in the view definition.

Comment: That should have been "select count(*) from view"

Comment: You can edit your original post...that is much more useful for future readers than adding a comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- I was facing the same error. That error is because user(other than root user) does not have permission to use that
  table.
- so first grant permission to user to use that table. Grant permission using *root user*.

```
grant select on database_name.table_name to user@localhost ;
```

In the same way you can grant permission for update or insert.